# webpack: Include node_modules packages in css-loader but exclude in css-modules

Tags: css, webpack, less, css-modules

My whole project style is writen in less syntax, in these files I also import some node_modules less file as references. For instance:

```
@import (reference) "~antd/lib/style/themes/default.less";
```

And here is part of webpack config to support this:

```
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loaders: [
      "style-loader",
      "css-loader",
      "less-loader"
    ]
  },
```

Notice I do not exclude `node_modules` directory

Now I want to support css modules syntax in my less file. So I enable it in `css-loader` options:

```
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loaders: [
      "style-loader",
       {
         loader: "css-loader",
         options: {
           modules: true
         }
       },
      "less-loader"
    ]
  },
```

However this cause a problem: because I am not exclude node_modules, the less file in node_modules also compiled by css modules, which conducting the package in node_modules not available

So is it possible include node_modules in css-loader but exclude them in css modules ?